# React understand only random keys?

Tags: javascript, random, reactjs, ref

I got really strange situation. I need to change value of input, if its not passed validation:

```
if (!isValid) {
  //if invalid set previous value
  this.timeInput.value = previous value;
}
```

I am using [masked input](https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput), but with vanilla inputs behaviour completely the same.

And I got situation that my input updates, just *before next rerender* was called. **Its my first question - why?** Ok, after some research i found the solution - 
add key to the input, as said there add -

`<input key={Math.random()}/>`

And its work! But there is strangest, when I tried to change value from random to my id property, something like -

`key={Number(this.props.id)}`

**It doesnt work!** Why? One difference its only that my id is whole number (like `3`), but `Math.random` return something like `0.21421214124`.

Component :

```
handleTimeBoxBlur = (e) => {
    const newTime = convertToSeconds(e.target.value)
    //if nothing was changed
    if (newTime === this.props.slide.seconds) {
      return;
    }

    const isValid = this.props.checkValidation(this.props.slide.id, newTime)
    if (!isValid) {
       //if invalid set previous value
       this.timeInput.value = formatSS(this.props.slide.seconds);
       setTimeout(() => this.setState({isValid : true}), 6000) //remove field highlighting after 8 seconds
    }

    this.setState({isValid : isValid})
 }

 render() {
    <input 
      key={Math.random()}  
      styleName={inputStyleName}
      onBlur={this.handleTimeBoxBlur}
      ref={ref => this.timeInput = ref} 
      defaultValue={formatSS(this.props.slide.seconds)} />
 }
```

Comment: Which React version are you using?

Comment: Im using React 15.4.2

Comment: And what do you mean by "it doesn't work?" Can you be more specific? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Input is updating, but return his value back on next `render()` call

Comment: Can you please post the Component's code? It's hard to understand with too little code

Comment: Why are you setting the value of the input like that instead of using the value prop? :/

Comment: Updated code, I am using Masked input plugin - its same as, to not complexing example - i change to familiar objects

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using [uncontrolled input component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (TL;DR you don't have any onChange method) and I wonder that it worked before you changed the key. I tried both ways and it didn't work. As it's stated [here](https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput#onchange--event-syntheticevent--any), you need to work with controlled components to get your expected behavior.

Try something like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isValid: false,
      textValue: props.slide.seconds
    }

    this.handleTimeBoxBlur = this.handleTimeBoxBlur.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ textValue: e.target.value })
  }

  handleTimeBoxBlur(e) {
    const newTime = this.state.textValue
    //if nothing was changed
    if (newTime === this.props.slide.seconds) {
      return;
    }

    const isValid = this.props.checkValidation(this.props.slide.id, newTime)

    if (!isValid) {
       //if invalid set previous value
       this.setState({textValue: this.props.slide.seconds});
       setTimeout(() => this.setState({isValid : true}), 6000) //remove field highlighting after 8 seconds
    }

    this.setState({isValid : isValid})
  }

   render() {
    return (
      <MaskedInput 
        key={this.props.slide.id}  
        mask={'11a'}
        onBlur={this.handleTimeBoxBlur} 
        value={this.state.textValue} 
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        );
 }
```

Comment: Thx for answer but I cant use controllled component here for several reasons

Comment: Then you can't use MaskedInput components, because they firmly state that its the only way to make things work